# AngularJS Factory return type undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I am attempting to store data in the database within an angularjs factory, and that is working for me. After storing data in Parse, I am trying to return either 1 or the error object (depending if store worked or not) and then handling that in the controller.

In the controller when I check the returned value, it neither 1 or error, but rather undefined.

Here is the code I have...

Controller Calling Service:

```
$scope.signup = function(user, $state) {

        if(user !== null)
        {
            var returnValue = CreateUserService.createAccount(user); 
            console.log("Return Value = " + returnValue);
            if(returnValue === 1)
            {
                $state.go('activate');   
            }else{
                console.log("Return Value was not appropriate");   
            }
        }else{
            console.log("Something went wrong while adding user");   
        }

    };
```

Factory:

```
.factory('CreateUserService', function() {
    return {
      createAccount: function(user) {
          var parseUser = new Parse.User();
          parseUser.set("username", user.username);
          parseUser.set("email", user.email);
          parseUser.set("name", user.name);
          parseUser.set("password", user.password);
          parseUser.set("mobile", user.mobile);

          /*Attempt to create user in DB*/
          parseUser.signUp(null, {
            success: function(parseUser) {
              // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
              //alert("success!");
              console.log("Stored");
                return 1;
            },
            error: function(parseUser, error) {
              // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
              //alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
              console.log("Error: " + error.message );    
              return error;
            }
          });
      }
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually return from the `createAccount` function, only from the callbacks. Also the callbacks are `asynchronous` so it will return before it has completed the request.

```
.factory('CreateUserService', function($q) {
    return {
      createAccount: function(user) {
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          var parseUser = new Parse.User();
          parseUser.set("username", user.username);
          parseUser.set("email", user.email);
          parseUser.set("name", user.name);
          parseUser.set("password", user.password);
          parseUser.set("mobile", user.mobile);

          /*Attempt to create user in DB*/
          parseUser.signUp(null, {
            success: function(parseUser) {
              // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
              //alert("success!");
              console.log("Stored");
              deferred.resolve(1);
            },
            error: function(parseUser, error) {
              // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
              //alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
              console.log("Error: " + error.message );    
              deferred.reject(error);
            }
          });

          return deferred.promise;
      }
    }
}
```

Then in your controller use the service function as a promise.

```
CreateUserService.createAccount(user).then(function(result) { 
   // result should be whatever passed in to resolve
}, function(error) {
  // error here will be whatever passed into reject
});
```

Learn more about promises: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: Hi Shaun...since i am new to AngularJS, can you please highlight your recommendation in code so that I can follow the suggestion.

Comment: It says $q not defined at object.createAccount

Comment: You've already accepted the other answer? Promises should be used not callbacks.

Comment: the other answer worked...the signup body in the controller was updated there, while your answer didnt recommend the same change. So I am trying to figure out your approach.

Comment: You need to understand dependency injection. See I have added $q in the function arguments, @Sandeeproops' answer is similar.

Comment: yes already added it..missed the injection. I understand it...but just need to practice it

Comment: What would deferred.resolve return? Because in the log am getting Return Value = [object Object]
UserAccessController.js:18 Return Value was not appropriate

Comment: You can have it return whatever you want. It will be passed to the promise handler

Comment: Are you using my resolve or the other answers. The other one uses data , which isn't defined I don't think .

Comment: am following your code here and trying to figure out how to check for one or error object back in the controller

Comment: Thanks working now I think...will have to test it more to confirm.

Comment: You're welcome. And I learnt something. I didn't know you could switch accepted answers! Best of luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96009/discussion-between-ksa-coder-and-shaun).

Answer (score 1):

I think issue is because of your ajax call asynchronous call. when you are calling "CreateUserService.createAccount(user)", it in turns call ajax call parseUser.signUp which is asynchronous.

```
.factory('CreateUserService', function($q) {
return {
  createAccount: function(user) {
      var parseUser = new Parse.User();
      parseUser.set("username", user.username);
      parseUser.set("email", user.email);
      parseUser.set("name", user.name);
      parseUser.set("password", user.password);
      parseUser.set("mobile", user.mobile);
      var deferred = $q.defer();  
      /*Attempt to create user in DB*/
      parseUser.signUp(null, {
        success: function(parseUser) {
          // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
          //alert("success!");
          console.log("Stored");
           // return 1;
           deferred.resolve(data);
        },
        error: function(parseUser, error) {
          // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
          //alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
          console.log("Error: " + error.message );    
          //return error;
          return deferred.resolve("Error while saving");
        }
      });
      return deferred.promise;
     }
   }
 }
```

Change your controller also with this
$scope.signup = function(user, $state) {

```
    if(user !== null)
    {
        var promise = CreateUserService.createAccount(user);
            promise.then(function(data) {
            $state.go('activate');
          },
          function(data) {
            console.log("Return Value was not appropriate");   
        });
    }else{
        console.log("Something went wrong while adding user");   
    }

};
```

This might resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are returning from a callback one step deep, so you need some sort of callback or angularJS's [$q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Similar issue: [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)

```
 $scope.signup = function(user, $state) {

    if(user !== null)
    {
        // notice the callback function passed below

        CreateUserService.createAccount(user, function(returnValue){

            // returnValue in available here for use

            console.log("Return Value = " + returnValue);
            if(returnValue === 1)
            {
                $state.go('activate');   
            }else{
                console.log("Return Value was not appropriate");   
            }
        });
    }else{
        console.log("Something went wrong while adding user");   
    }
};
```

Factory:

```
    .factory('CreateUserService', function() {
    return {
      createAccount: function(user, done) {

         // done callback function in the param to be called for returning the values 

          var parseUser = new Parse.User();
          parseUser.set("username", user.username);
          parseUser.set("email", user.email);
          parseUser.set("name", user.name);
          parseUser.set("password", user.password);
          parseUser.set("mobile", user.mobile);

          /*Attempt to create user in DB*/
          parseUser.signUp(null, {
            success: function(parseUser) {
              // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
              //alert("success!");
              console.log("Stored");

              // call the done/callback here for success
                done(1);

            },
            error: function(parseUser, error) {
              // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
              //alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
              console.log("Error: " + error.message );    

              // call the done/callback here for error
              done(error);

            }
          });
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! I will review it to make sure lesson learned :)

Comment: Can you delete your other answer on this post. It seems to have been repeated

Comment: Thanks Shaun.. Sorry didn't notice that happening.